# How to remove duplicate entries from model list in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-2

I have Registration list which has duplicate entries in it for student then how can i remove these duplicate entries in razor view. I know that i can handle this in c# but I want to remove duplicate entries in razor view.
Below is my code:-

```
  foreach (var stud in Model.Registrations)
                {
                    <text> @registration.Student.FirstName @stud.Student.LastName </text><br />
                }
```

what is the statement for that. is it something like this:-

```
       foreach (var stud in Model.Registrations.GroupBy(s => s.Student.ID).Select(g => g.First()))
    {
      // Student Name and ID
    }
```

Above statement is not work for me. What is the code to do this?

Comment: Firstly data manipulation is recommended in controller. Use a ViewModel with all the data setup the way you want. However, If you want your above statement to work try by adding a .List() at end of GroupBy or Select.

Comment: Define "duplicate".  If your model encapsulates that logic in `GetHashCode` and `Equals` overrides then you can just use `.Distinct()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var stud in Model.Registrations.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.First()).ToList())
  {
     <text> @stud.Student.FirstName @stud.Student.LastName </text><br />
  }
```

use any one unique column to get unique rows in the "GroupBy(x => x.Id)" 
here i am using Id(as example), so that you will not get duplicate rows...